# Frequency of one dataframe rows from another dataframe

Tags: r

Can someone help me how to count from another dataframe?

df1(out)

```
structure(list(Item = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = "0S1576"), LC = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), class = "factor", .Label = c("MW92", 
"OY01", "RM11")), Fiscal.Month = c("2019-M06", "2019-M07", "2019-M06", 
"2019-M07", "2019-M08", "2019-M09", "2019-M06", "2019-M07", "2019-M08"
)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

df2(tempdf)

```
structure(list(Item = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "0S1576", class = "factor"), 
    LC = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("MW92", "OY01", "RM11", "RS11", 
    "WK14", "WK15"), class = "factor"), Fiscal.Month = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2019-M06", 
    "2019-M07", "2019-M08", "2019-M09"), class = "factor"), fcst = c(22L, 
    21L, 20L, 19L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 10L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to count the frequency of Item,LC,Fiscal.month of df1 from df2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count using `table` and merge `df1` with `df2` by using `factor` and you need `interaction` as you use more than one column to merge.

```
table(factor(interaction(df2[c("Item","LC","Fiscal.Month")]), levels=interaction(df1)))
#0S1576.MW92.2019-M06 0S1576.MW92.2019-M07 0S1576.OY01.2019-M06 
#                   2                    1                    3 
#0S1576.OY01.2019-M07 0S1576.OY01.2019-M08 0S1576.OY01.2019-M09 
#                   0                    0                    0 
#0S1576.RM11.2019-M06 0S1576.RM11.2019-M07 0S1576.RM11.2019-M08 
#                   3                    0                    0
```

Or a speed improved version using `match` and `tabulate`:

```
(df1$freq <-  tabulate(match(interaction(df2[c("Item","LC","Fiscal.Month")]), interaction(df1)), nrow(df1)))
#[1] 2 1 3 0 0 0 3 0 0
```

Or sometimes even faster using `fastmatch`:

```
library(fastmatch)
df1$freq <-  tabulate(fmatch(interaction(df2[c("Item","LC","Fiscal.Month")]), interaction(df1)), nrow(df1))
```

Comment: Can I store it in a dataframe rather than a table??